# How to get next and previous step element in bootstrap tour js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

we can get current step element by

```
var step = tour._options.steps[tour.getCurrentStep()];
var element=$(step.element);
```

Same as is there is any way to get next and previous step element in bootstrap tour js on onNext() and onPrev().

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: something like var nStep = getStep(tour.getCurrentStep() + 1)// next step?

Answer (score 2):

The best way i think is this:

```
var step = tour._options.steps[tour.getCurrentStep()];
var element=$(step.element);

var step=tour.getStep(step - 1);
```

Comment: please check if the step index is not already 0 and is not currentStep.ended()